# ParametricNDSolve Skipping Over Periodic Input Function

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I am attemting to model some expermental data with the differential equation $\frac{dm}{dt} = D(m) + F(\omega t)$ via Mathematica's `ParametricNDSolveValue` function. I managed to achieve a fitting, however, upon ploting result $m(t)$ a clear discrepancy with the parent equations can be noted. Briefly, a cell of angular width $\Delta \theta$ passes under a stream of water centered about $\theta = 0$ with the amount of water gained by the cell modeled by the function $F(\theta)$. A small hole in the bottom causes the water to drain out at a rate of $D(m(t)) = -(k_0 + k_1 * m(t)) $ for $m(t) > 0 $ and $D(m(t)) = 0 $ for $m(t) \leq 0$ with $k_1$ and $k_0$ being fit parameters.

When I ask Mathematica to plot the input function $F(\theta)$ it, as expected, returns peroidic spikes every $\frac{2 * \pi}{\omega}$. However, when I put in my parameters $k_1$ and $k_0$ the mass function does not show the expected spike every $\frac{2 * \pi}{\omega}$. At first I thought it may be a time step issue so I decreased it to an unreasonably small value, but still no luck.

Is there a Method that I sould speify or a boundry condition to add to the solve inorder to make the peaks appear? Below are my code and plots.

```
(*Physical Constants*)
R = 0.229;
r = 0.003175;
Ncells = 36;
Q0 = 0.02103;
\[CapitalDelta]\[Theta] = 2 Pi/Ncells;
\[Phi]1 = ArcCos[Sqrt[(1 - r^2/R^2)]];

(*Fit Constants*)
parms = {k0 -> 0.0009110028878465301, 
   k1 -> 0.023578559769871447, \[Omega] -> 1.501};
```

```
(*Functions*)
Q[\[Theta]max_, \[Theta]min_] := (2*Q0)/
  Pi ((R/(2 r) Sin[\[Theta]max] Sqrt[1 - (R/r Sin[\[Theta]max])^2] - 
      ArcTan[Sqrt[1 - (R/r Sin[\[Theta]max])^2]/(
       1 + (R/r Sin[\[Theta]max]))]) - (R/(2 r) Sin[\[Theta]min] Sqrt[
       1 - (R/r Sin[\[Theta]min])^2] - 
      ArcTan[Sqrt[1 - (R/r Sin[\[Theta]min])^2]/(
       1 + (R/r Sin[\[Theta]min]))]))
F3[\[Theta]_] := Piecewise[
  
  {{0 , (\[Phi]1 + \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]/2) <= Abs[\[Theta]]}},
  Q[s[\[Theta] + \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]/2], 
   s[\[Theta] - \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta]/2]]
  ]
s[\[Theta]_] := 
 If[Abs[\[Theta]] >= \[Phi]1, \[Theta]/Abs[\[Theta]]*\[Phi]1, \[Theta]]
Ftemp[\[Theta]_] := F3[Mod[\[Theta] + Pi, 2 Pi] - Pi]
Dtemp[m_] := Piecewise[{{-(k0 + k1*m[t]), m[t] > 0}}, 0]
```

[image: F vs Time]

```
mFun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{m'[t] == 
    Dtemp[m] + Re@Ftemp[(\[Omega]*t - \[CapitalDelta]\[Theta])], 
   m[0] == 0}, m, {t, 0, 20, \[Phi]1/300000}, {\[Omega], k0, k1}]
mCell = mFun[\[Omega], k0, k1] /. parms;
Plot[mCell[t], {t, 0, 20}, 
 GridLines -> {2 Pi/1.501*Range[0, 8], None}, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Time [s]", "Mass [Kg]"}]
```

[image: Mass in a Cell]

Note: the vertical grid-lines are where peaks are expected.

Below I changed the parameters around to show what the fourm of the graph above should be.

```
mCell = mFun[1.501, 0.000000001, 2.8];
Plot[mCell[t], {t, 0, 20}, 
 GridLines -> {2 Pi/1.501*Range[0, 8], None}, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Time [s]", "Mass [Kg]"}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Realistic Results]

Any help/advice would be amazing!